# Strikethrough text in a Manim Table

Tags: python, animation, manim

Here is the source code of the [documentation page of Table](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.table.Table.html) in Manim:

```py
class TableExamples(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        t0 = Table(
            [["This", "is a"],
            ["simple", "Table in \n Manim."]])
        t1 = Table(
            [["This", "is a"],
            ["simple", "Table."]],
            row_labels=[Text("R1"), Text("R2")],
            col_labels=[Text("C1"), Text("C2")])
        t1.add_highlighted_cell((2,2), color=YELLOW)
        t2 = Table(
            [["This", "is a"],
            ["simple", "Table."]],
            row_labels=[Text("R1"), Text("R2")],
            col_labels=[Text("C1"), Text("C2")],
            top_left_entry=Star().scale(0.3),
            include_outer_lines=True,
            arrange_in_grid_config={"cell_alignment": RIGHT})
        t2.add(t2.get_cell((2,2), color=RED))
        t3 = Table(
            [["This", "is a"],
            ["simple", "Table."]],
            row_labels=[Text("R1"), Text("R2")],
            col_labels=[Text("C1"), Text("C2")],
            top_left_entry=Star().scale(0.3),
            include_outer_lines=True,
            line_config={"stroke_width": 1, "color": YELLOW})
        t3.remove(*t3.get_vertical_lines())
        g = Group(
            t0,t1,t2,t3
        ).scale(0.7).arrange_in_grid(buff=1)
        self.add(g)
```

I'm trying to strikethrough something. To do so I got inspired by [this documentation page](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/_modules/manim/mobject/text/text_mobject.html?highlight=strikethrough#). Hence why, I've tried:

```py
class TableExamples(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        t0 = Table(
            [['``<span strikethrough="true" strikethrough_color="red">This</span>``', "is a"],
            ["simple", "Table in \n Manim."]])
        t1 = Table(
            [["This", "is a"],
            ["simple", "Table."]],
            row_labels=[Text("R1"), Text("R2")],
            col_labels=[Text("C1"), Text("C2")])
        t1.add_highlighted_cell((2,2), color=YELLOW)
        t2 = Table(
            [["This", "is a"],
            ["simple", "Table."]],
            row_labels=[Text("R1"), Text("R2")],
            col_labels=[Text("C1"), Text("C2")],
            top_left_entry=Star().scale(0.3),
            include_outer_lines=True,
            arrange_in_grid_config={"cell_alignment": RIGHT})
        t2.add(t2.get_cell((2,2), color=RED))
        t3 = Table(
            [["This", "is a"],
            ["simple", "Table."]],
            row_labels=[Text("R1"), Text("R2")],
            col_labels=[Text("C1"), Text("C2")],
            top_left_entry=Star().scale(0.3),
            include_outer_lines=True,
            line_config={"stroke_width": 1, "color": YELLOW})
        t3.remove(*t3.get_vertical_lines())
        g = Group(
            t0,t1,t2,t3
        ).scale(0.7).arrange_in_grid(buff=1)
        self.add(g)
```

But it doesn't work. I've also tried using LaTeX tags, but Manim doesn't understand it as LaTeX because (I think?) this is interpreted as `Text` and not `Tex`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation of `Table`](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.table.Table.html), you want to adapt the `element_to_mobject` keyword argument (because you are trying to use `MarkupText` syntax in a "normal" `Text` class, which does not work.

This does though:

```py
class TableExamples(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        t0 = Table(
            [['<span strikethrough="true" strikethrough_color="red">This</span>', "is a"],
            ["simple", "Table in \n Manim."]],
            element_to_mobject=MarkupText)
        self.add(t0)
```

Comment: Thanks ! That works. However, what if I want to strikethrough in a MathTable. To strikethrough in a Tex object, I need to pass the argument `tex_template=my_template` (because I need to use a package) to the Tex object but I don't find any where to pass this argument in the MathTable documentation (https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.table.MathTable.html?highlight=MathTable)

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows you can set your template as the default template for `MathTex` by running `MathTex.set_default(tex_template=my_template)`, or define your own custom class derived from `MathTex` with the desired default settings -- and then use `element_to_mobject=YourCustomMathTex`.